# mate-terminal always opens maximized, want open at size specified by defined default profile (not install default)

Tags: launcher, ubuntu-mate, customization

Linux OasisMega1 **5.4.0-52-generic** #57-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 10:57:00 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**mate-terminal** Version 1.24.0.2ubuntu1

In panel button, having set my preferred profile to "**Terminal_Oasis_DEFAULT**", I have tried following:

- mate-terminal --geometry="150x18+0+0"  (doesn't open)
- "mate-terminal --geometry=150x18+0+0"  (doesn't open)
- mate-terminal --geometry=150x18  (doesn't open)
- mate-terminal  (opens maximized)

[image: Preferences selection of local-custom profile as default]

[image: Properties of chosen local-custom default profile]

[image: Properties defined for mate-terminal launcher]

The Queer thing is that if I change the preferences to choose the **distro Default profile**, and update that to my custom geometry definition, it will open correctly sized and positionned !!!

Is that a bug? or am I missing something?

I prefer to leave the Distro's default profile **un-modified** as a failsafe to avoid creating a corrupted file from which I cannot recover.

[image: Preferences selection of distro-default profile]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is to proceed as follows:

1. Open "MATE Tweak".
2. Click on the "Windows" icon in the left column.
3. Click to place a checkmark in the box next to "do not auto-maximize new windows".  This is seen in the image below.

That makes the change permanent and fixes the problem!

[image]